# PHP - How to specify MySQL row name instead of number in mysql_result

Tags: php, mysql

I have a MySQL database table with 2 fields - username and score. I want the result of a mysql select query to show the score of someone with a particular username. How would I do this?

Here is the current code: mysql_result($result, 0)

Is there any way that I can make the person's username act as a row name/number?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `row` parameter in [mysql_result](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-result.php) must be a number. However, you can just refactor your query to search on `username`. Assuming `username` is unique you can do:

```
$res = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE username = 'john'");
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res);
echo $row['score'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Finding the score of a particular username is done in the sql query.

```
$res   = mysql_query("SELECT username,score FROM table WHERE username='user1' LIMIT 1");
$user  = mysql_result($res,0);
$score = mysql_result($res,0,1);
```